# What is the right way to validate a StoreKit 2 transaction jwsRepresentation in python?

Tags: python, swift, jwt, storekit

It's unclear from the docs what you actually do to verify the [jwsRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/verificationresult/3868429-jwsrepresentation) string from a StoreKit 2 transaction on the server side.

Also "signedPayload" from the [Apple App Store Notifications V2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/signedpayload) seems to be the same, but there is also no documentation around actually validating that either outside of validating it client side on device.

What gives? What do we do with this JWS/JWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(DISCLAIMER: I am a crypto novice so check me on this if I'm using the wrong terms, etc. throughout)

The JWS in `jwsRepresentation`, and the `signedPayload` in the Notification V2 JSON body, are JWTs — you can take one and check it out at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). The job is to validate the JWT signature and extract the payload once you're sufficiently convinced it's really from Apple. Then the payload itself contains information you can use to upgrade the user's account/etc. server side once the data is trusted.

To validate the JWT, you need to find the signature that the JWT is signed with, specified in the JWT header's `"x5c"` collection, validate the certificate chain, and then validate that the signature is really from Apple.

**STEP ONE**: Load the well-known root & intermediate certs from Apple.

```
import requests
from OpenSSL import crypto

ROOT_CER_URL = "https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleRootCA-G3.cer"
G6_CER_URL = "https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG6.cer"

root_cert_bytes: bytes = requests.get(ROOT_CER_URL).content
root_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, root_cert_bytes)

g6_cert_bytes: bytes = requests.get(G6_CER_URL).content
g6_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, g6_cert_bytes)
```

**STEP TWO**: Get certificate chain out of the JWT header

```
import jwt  # PyJWT library

# Get the signing keys out of the JWT header. The header will look like:
# {"alg": "ES256", "x5c": ["...base64 cert...", "...base64 cert..."]}
header = jwt.get_unverified_header(apple_jwt_string)

provided_certificates: List[crypto.X509] = []
for cert_base64 in header['x5c']:
    cert_bytes = base64url_decode(cert_base64)
    cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert_bytes)
    provided_certificates.append(cert)
```

**STEP THREE**: Validate the chain is what you think it is -- this ensures the cert chain is signed by the real Apple root & intermediate certs.

```
# First make sure these are the root & intermediate certs from Apple:
assert provided_certificates[-2].digest('sha256') == g6_cert.digest('sha256')
assert provided_certificates[-1].digest('sha256') == root_cert.digest('sha256')

# Now validate that the cert chain is cryptographically legit:
store = crypto.X509Store()
store.add_cert(root_cert)
store.add_cert(g6_cert)
for cert in provided_certificates[:-2]:
    try:
        crypto.X509StoreContext(store, cert).verify_certificate()
    except crypto.X509StoreContextError:
        logging.error("Invalid certificate chain in JWT: %s", apple_jwt)
        return None
    store.add_cert(cert)
```

**FINALLY**: Load & validate the JWT using the now-trusted certificate in the header.

```
# Now that the cert is validated, we can use it to verify the actual signature
# of the JWT. PyJWT does not understand this certificate if we pass it in, so
# we have to get the cryptography library's version of the same key:
cryptography_version_of_key = provided_certificates[0].get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()
try:
    return jwt.decode(apple_jwt, cryptography_version_of_key, algorithms=["ES256"])
except Exception:
    logging.exception("Problem validating Apple JWT")
    return None
```

Voila you now have a validated JWT body from the App Store at your disposal.

Gist of entire solution: https://gist.github.com/taylorhughes/3968575b40dd97f851f35892931ebf3e